# Какой процент пользователей блокирует рекламу в приложениях на Android?

Tags: android

Какой процент пользователей блокирует рекламу в приложениях на Android?

Comment: Отдельно в Вашем приложении? На какой платформе? Как блокирует?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вопрос слишком обобщенный и требует уточнения. Но, если Вам подойдет обобщенный ответ, тогда вот: весьма незначительный процент пользователей блокирует рекламу на телефоне (в случае, если приложение загружено из *Play Market*). Почему я так думаю:

1. Я не встречал блокировщиков рекламы в приложениях, а значит блокировщики не доступны для широких масс.
2. Категория людей, которая отключает интернет, чтобы отключить рекламу тоже весьма мала и то, если приложение не работает без интернета — такой способ не работает.
3. Категория людей, которая "вскрывает" приложение и изменяет код, чтобы убрать рекламу не представляет даже 1% от всей массы пользователей.

Однако, есть люди, которые загружают взломанные приложения из сети, но такую категорию пользователей я не считаю потенциально полезными для приложения.

Comment: Доп. вопрос. Как думаете почему Гугл не удаляет AdBlock из интернет-магазина хром? В google play приложения AdBlock которое блокировало бы рекламу в других приложениях и вправду нет. Только браузер есть.

Comment: @Khipster, насколько я знаю, Adblock Browser — это отдельный браузер,  то есть отдельное приложение. А в своем приложении — они делают, что хотят (тем более, что там не только гугловская реклама :D).

Comment: @Khipster, и примите, пожалуйста, ответ, если он Вам помог.